# PhpStorm function call custom/standard: possible to have different colors?

Tags: php, phpstorm

As you see in my screenshot below, I have two functions: A standard php function `strlen()` and a custom php function `foo()`.

[image: screenshot]

I would like to have 2 different colors for the different types of functions: standard in blue and custom in black.

Here are my settings:

[image: settings]

Could somebody help me to have 2 different colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is no longer possible since PhpStorm 2016.1 -- such functionality was removed.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-30540#comment=27-1284395